# Почему повторяются item в listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public class GuestsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Typeface avenirnextbold;
Typeface avenirnextregular;
LinearLayout guests_cancel_linear;
ImageView guests_cancel_imageView;
String text0;
String text1;
String text2;
String text3;
String text4;


Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<guestList> worldpopulationlist2 = null;
private ArrayList<guestList> arraylist;

public GuestsListViewAdapter(Context context,List<guestList> worldpopulationlist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist2 = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<guestList>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);

   }

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist2.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist2.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guests_listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count_guests);
        guests_cancel_linear = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.guests_cancel_linear);
        guests_cancel_imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.guests_cancel_imageView);



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    try {

        holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist2.get(position).getName() + " ");
        holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist2.get(position).getSurname()+ " ");

        if(worldpopulationlist2.get(position).getName().equals("app") || worldpopulationlist2.get(position).getName().equals("app"))
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setMinimumHeight(0);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
        }

        double i = worldpopulationlist2.get(position).getGuests();
        int b = (int) i;
        if(b == 1) {


            holder.population.setText(text1 + String.valueOf(worldpopulationlist2.get(position)
                    .getGuests())+ text2);
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 0, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumWidth(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxWidth(px);
        }
        else if(b == 2 || b ==3 || b ==4) {

            holder.population.setText(text1 + String.valueOf(worldpopulationlist2.get(position)
                    .getGuests())+ text3);
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 0, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumWidth(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxWidth(px);
        }

        else if(b == 0) {

            holder.population.setText("");
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 0, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumWidth(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxWidth(px);
        }

        else if(b == -1) {

            guests_cancel_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.guest_cancel);

        }


        else {

            holder.population.setText(text0 + text1 + String.valueOf(worldpopulationlist2.get(position)
                    .getGuests())+ text4);
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 0, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_linear.setMinimumWidth(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxHeight(px);
            guests_cancel_imageView.setMaxWidth(px);

        }







        }




    }
    catch (Exception exp){}
    return view;
}
```

}

Почему повторяются item в listView?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790412/list-view-items-changes-position-when-scrolling-android/28791031#28791031).

Необходимо в Адаптер добавить вот эти 2 метода:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```